# Need help in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code:

```
<div id="comments" class="clearfix">
  <div class="conversation box_round_s box_shadow clearfix mtm">
  <div class="conversation box_round_s box_shadow clearfix mtm">
    <input class="conv_tracker" type="hidden" value="4695f1db2d">
    <div class="conv-header">2</div>
    <div class="comment pts plm prs pbs">
    <div class="comment plxl pts plm prs pbs">
    <div class="replybox pvs clearfix">
      <textarea class="comment_txt_r fses fft"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="conversation box_round_s box_shadow clearfix mtm">
  <div class="conversation box_round_s box_shadow clearfix mtm">
</div>
```

and I'm trying to read the value of input with class conv_tracker (4th line in code with value="4695f1db2d"). I want to read this value. I'm reading it when someone presses enter in textarea. there are multiple text areas on page. I'm using following jquery:

the code does enter inside the if, but shows undefined.

```
$(".comment_txt_r").keydown(function(e){
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if(code == 13) {      
    var ctext = $(this).val();
    var relid = $(this).closest('.conversation').children('input.conv_tracker').val();
    alert(relid);
  }
});
```

can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see the class `comment_txt_r` anywhere in your provided HTML.

Comment: thanks, i have corrected the code.

Comment: `<textarea class="comment_txt_r fses fft" />` `textarea` is **not** a self closing tag. :S

Comment: Don't keep changing the code in your OP. It makes answering your question impossible.

Comment: corrected that too, but that's not my problem. please suggest how do i access the value.

Comment: Added a [complete solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12514047/144665) dividing actions per conversation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$('#conv_tracker').val()`. The ID must be unique within the page, so there is no reason to traverse up and down the DOM via `closest` and `children`, and then select by ID. Just select by ID.

It's very likely that if your current code isn't working, the ID is *not* unique within the page, and it's being stripped off the later elements with duplicate IDs preventing your code from selecting the element. If this is the case, you need to use a class or some other attribute for the repeated elements.

---

As an unrelated suggestion, try using `data` attributes and attaching the value directly to the element you're binding the events to, rather than dumping random, uncoupled, semantically meaningless elements into the DOM.

Your text area gets a `data-conv-tracker` attribute:

```
<textarea class="comment_txt_r fses fft" data-conv-tracker="4695f1db2d" />
```

And your code is simplified drastically with no additional selection/DOM traversal:

```
if(code == 13) {      
  var ctext = $(this).val();
  var relid = $(this).data('conv-tracker');
  alert(relid);
}
```

Comment: @Phil if this doesn't solve his issue, he has other issues outside the code he's posted.

Comment: thanks. ok, so i changed the id to class, but now also i get undefined error.

Comment: @meagar thanks for your suggestion. I tried your approach (conv-tracker one) but I am still getting undefined error. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
var relid = $(this).closest('.conversation').children('input#conv_tracker').val();
```

to

```
var relid = $('#conv_tracker').val()
```

You are using `$(this)` in the wrong context (it is $('.comment_txt_r') in your code)

Comment: see, there are multiple text boxes with class comment_txt_r in the code, and also the multiple hidden inputs with different values. so I need to have a way to access only that input value in which user is currently pressing "enter".

Comment: alright, then you cannot use id's but should be using classes. An id is unique thus you will not access the right element the way you are using it.

Comment: @Rahul Please see my answer on data attributes. You're doing this in a very dated and ugly way. You should not be using ids *or* classes for this.

Comment: I think you might just have to change it to `var relid = $(this).closest('.conversation').children('input.conv_tracker').val();`

Comment: I agree with @meagar though. If you actually can alter the source code of the html, you could just attach that value to the textarea itself.

Comment: @meagar thanks for your suggestion. I tried your approach too. I still get an error even when i use your approach (data attributes). I'm currently using:

$(".comment_txt_r").keydown(function(e){
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if(code == 13) {  
    var ctext = $(this).val();
    var relid = $(this).data('conv-tracker');
    alert(relid);
  }
});

i'm getting undefined error. please help.

Comment: @Rahul have you tried `var relid = $(this).closest('.conversation').children('input.conv_tracker').val();`?

Answer (score 0):

Just address the input directly in jQuery like this `$('#conv_tracker').val()`. So your code would look like:

```
$(".comment_txt_r").keydown(function(e){
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if(code == 13) {      
    var ctext = $(this).val();
    var relid = $('#conv_tracker').val();
    alert(relid);
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 ID is fine without complicating it up with tag type (again).

Comment: Aha yes it is, I had copied and pasted from question, now removed.

Comment: see, there are multiple text boxes with class comment_txt_r in the code, and also the multiple hidden inputs with different values. so I need to have a way to access only that input value in which user is currently pressing "enter".

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

Replace `<textarea class="comment_txt_r fses fft" />`

With `<textarea class="comment_txt_r fses fft"></textarea>`

**JavaScript**

```
$('#comments .conversation').each(function(i, conversation){    
    $('.comment_txt_r', conversation).keydown(function(e){
      if((e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) == 13) {      
        var ctext = $(this).val();
        var relid = $('.conv_tracker', conversation).val();
        alert(relid);
      }
    });
    // additional per conversation code
});
```

By running through each conversation individually you give jQuery a smaller group of elements to filter through.